# hangfire job cancellation doesn't happen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, hangfire

I have .Net core 3.1 Web api project. There is a method to call separate API for getting some values.

This is my code

Define instance variable

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Looping through my values. There is separate method and user call the method when he wants.

```
 foreach (var no in nos)
 {
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => webServiceCall(no, tokenSource));//loop and give jobs to hangfire
 }
```

WebServiceCall implementation

```
    public async Task webServiceCall(int no, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44359/api/process/" + no, tokenSource.Token);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var val = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returned Value : " + val);
                    //logic code
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Get request canceled." + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works and I need to cancel above batch from separate API. I try something like this and it doesn't work.

```
[HttpGet("CancellingJob")]
public async Task HagfireCancel()
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

But when I call to this, all processes happens as usual and did not canceled.... Can any one help me to cancel hangfire jobs?

I used Hangfire 1.7.0 version.